# why is my datatoggle not working in bootstrap?

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-4

I can see icon when I clicked in mobile mode but the icon is not working. I am adding my code below.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-success navbar-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> DreamTeam </a>
    <button
      class="navbar-toggler"
      data-toggle="collapse"
      data-target="#mynav"
    >
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mynav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Dashboard</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      
    </div>
  </nav>
  
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <h1>Welcome to Angular</h1>
    <h2>Hello</h2>
  </div>
```

I have installed jquery and bootstrap from npm in my angular project and added it also.

```
"styles": [
              
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": ["./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
            ]
```

Comment: make sure you should have bootstrap js file in your project `bootstrap.js` for toggle.

Comment: I added bootstrap.js, still same problem @Prakash Rajotiya

Answer (score 0):

More a suggestion than answer, but when you want to use Bootstrap with Angular it is better (at least in my experience) to use something like ngx-bootstrap.
https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/

Not the greatest idea to use jQuery with Angular since jQuery itself doesn't provide anything Angular provides out of the box. Its possible jQuery executed code could by-pass Angular's built in security, such as its built in sanitation.

Downside is sometimes you have to wait for NGX-Bootstrap to catch up (like now for Bootstrap 5)

Answer (score 0):

In this line of your code `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mynav">` Update code as per shown in below code...

```
<div class="navbar-collapse" id="mynav" [class.collapse]="navbarCollapsed">
```

**in component.ts file**

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

    navbarCollapsed = true;
}
```

basicaaly, you need to bind `collapse` bootstrap class with angular.